# How to download excel/Zip files in Angular 4

Tags: excel, angular, file, download

I am using angular 4 as frond end and lumen 5.4 as back end.

My requirement is to export some data as excel and zip file.

Using import `{ saveAs }` from `'file-saver/FileSaver';` package for file download.

**Angular 4 Code:**

```
downloadExcel() {

const type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
const headers = { headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': type }) };
const filename = 'file.xls';

this.http.get('http://10.2.2.109/Download/exportExcel', headers)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response, type, filename));

return false;


}



private saveToFileSystem(response, __type, filename) {
    const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');

if (contentDispositionHeader !== null) {
  const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
  //const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
  const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: __type });
  saveAs(blob, filename);
} else {
  alert('Cant download.....');
  // handling download condition if content disposition is empty
  const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: __type });
  saveAs(blob, filename);
}


}
```

**Lumen Code**

```
public function exportExcel(Request $request) {
        $file = storage_path();
        $file_name = 'book1.xls';
        $headers = [
            'Content-type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="' . $file_name,
            'X-Filename' => $file_name,
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
            'Content-Length' => filesize($file . '/' . $file_name),
            'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0',
            'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=1',
            'Expires' => 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
            'Last-Modified' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT',
            'Cache-Control' => 'cache, must-revalidate',
            'Pragma' => 'public',
            'Set-Cookie' => 'fileDownload=true; path=/',
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => 'Content-Length,Cache-Control,Content-Language,Content-Type,Expires,Last-Modified,Pragma'
        ];

        return response()->download($file . '/' . $file_name, $file_name, $headers);
    }
```

**Issues**

1. `const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');` seems always empty.
2. We cant open downloaded file, shows corrupted message.
3. It working for text file download

Please help me to resolve this issue. OR specify any other working code//package for angular

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
downloadExcel() {

  const type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
  const filename = 'file.xls';
  const options = new RequestOptions({
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
            headers: new Headers({ 'Accept': type })
        });

  this.http.get('http://10.2.2.109/Download/exportExcel', options)
           .catch(errorResponse => Observable.throw(errorResponse.json()))
           .map((response) => { 
                 if (response instanceof Response) {
                    return response.blob();
                 }
                 return response;
            })
           .subscribe(data => saveAs(data, filename),
                      error => console.log(error)); // implement your error handling here

}
```

The key points are `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob` on the RequestOptions and `response.blob()` when getting back the response.

In general, it's not recommended to access the `_body` property of the response like this: `response._body`, but instead you should call the relevant method to get the body content based on its type (like `response.blob()`, `response.json()`, etc)

Comment: Thank you :)
One more doubt, how to modify the service to access both json data and blob data.

The condition is  we are passing authorization headers along with the request, if authorization fails or unable to generate excel API will return json. In that condition how we can change service to access response type to handle blob as well as json data.

Comment: See my updated code sample for a possible solution. I added a catch operator that would catch any HTTP error responses (so basically HTTP error codes > 400), and would then extract the json out of the response, creating a new Observable with that content. Then, in the map you would have to check if the input is an instance of Response to extract the blob (the happy case), or if not just pass the content on (the error case). Bear in mind this is not tested, so I am not sure it will work. However, at least it should give you some ideas I hope :)

Comment: Except blob data all other conditions we are returning json data with status code 200. In this case how we can handle.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't :). You should use HTTP codes for error conditions, such as 401 for unauthorized or 400 for bad request. Otherwise, I don't really see how you could distinguish between a successful response and an error. I guess you could try in the map function response.blob() inside a try block, and then response.json() in a catch block...but it's pretty ugly tbh

Comment: As I am new to angular please advise me, for the  above mentioned scenario what is the genius method to wrote code.

Comment: How to catch error messages. If the http status is not 200. Right now we are using catch and subscribe response that are not able to get the response body. Only getting error. Statustext

Comment: Works! for me but i have change ```responseType: 'blob'```, this works for me of both files ```.csv``` & ```.xlsx``` type files. Please find my code.... ```return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' });```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) provided the input data is in JSON format. The output of the function will be CSV which can be opened in Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets.

Install the package:

```
$ npm install json2csv --save
```

Add the following to your component:

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
var result = json2csv({ data: myData, fields: fields });
```