# Fetch binary data (xls, pdfs, csvs) with angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to apply this solution: [How to download excel/Zip files in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153118/how-to-download-excel-zip-files-in-angular-4/46154191#46154191)
But I am having some errors.

The code on my service is this:

```
    return this.http.post(endpoint, 
                          body, 
                         {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Accept':'application/vnd.ms-excel'}) , 
                          responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
                     .map(res => res.blob());
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'.

Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
Type 'ResponseContentType.Blob' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
```

I have no idea what to do about it :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making responseType:"blob" solved my issue!

```
return this.http.post(endpoint, body, {responseType: "blob"}).map(res => res).catch(this.handleError);
```