# Downloading multiple screenshots in one zip file angular

Tags: angular6, screenshot, html2canvas

Is it possible to download a collection of screenshots in one zip file using angular html2canvas ?

Comment: have you  tried by using java script

Comment: No, I am using angular typescript, but if you have a way with js, support me with it, please
may be it helps me @AsiyaFatima

Comment: Refer this URL'S maybe it will help you 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099549/is-it-possible-to-generate-zip-file-and-download-in-angular-4            https://community.canvaslms.com/thread/6489   https://gist.github.com/noelvo/4502eea719f83270c8e9

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ^^ @AsiyaFatima