# GZipStream exception in Server side when decompressing JSZip compressed file

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, gzipstream, jszip

I am working on ASP.net core Web API in server side and Angular 8 on Client side.

I need to compress a list of files and send to server and decompress in server. I use JSZip in client side to compress and my client side code is:

```
zipAndAddFileToUploader2(file: File): void {
    const fileName = file.name
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    let self = this;
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
           throw err;
        }
        var zip = new JSZip();
        zip.file(fileName, data);
        zip.generateAsync({type:'blob', compression: 'DEFLATE', compressionOptions: { level: 9 }})
             .then(function(content) {
                var file_object = new File([content], fileName, {type: 'application/zip'});
                self.uploader.addToQueue([file_object]);
            });
    });
}
```

My Server side is as follows:

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (MemoryStream decompressedFileStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decompressedFileStream.Position = 0;
            decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);//Exception ****
            byteArray = decompressedFileStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

CopyTo(decompressedFileStream) throws following exception:

Exception : The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.

Exception details:

```
at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadInflateOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32& bytesRead)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, Int32& bytesRead)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateVerified(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.CopyToStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.CopyToStream.CopyFromSourceToDestination()
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
   at MyApp.MyService.Decompress(Byte[] data) in C:\...\MyService.cs:line 125
   at MyApp.MyService.<UpdateMyFile>d__24.MoveNext() in C:\...\MyService.cs:line 137
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you try creating a much simpler zip file first? `let zip = new JSZip(); zip.file("hello.txt", "Hello world!")` just to see if it's a server or client side problem. And also test the uploader you're using with just a hello world txt file to see if you can receive and open that correctly server side. "An uncompressed compression method" could probably also mean that it's just garbage it doesn't recognize and not a correct zip file at all.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks, it gives me the same exception: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.

Comment: Can you try using the npm package `file-saver` to generate a blob URL and download the zip instead of sending it to the server (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52690053/1016004)? If that works, try sending it to something like https://webhook.site in a JSON body, open Notepad and paste the received contents, then save as .zip, and see if that still works.

Comment: This kind of troubleshooting can help narrow down during which part of the whole workflow the data is garbled.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be useful to someone.
The problem was in Server side. I changed the code and it is working. Thanks v much all your comments.

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream);
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.Entries.FirstOrDefault();
    if (null == entry)
        return null;

    var stream1 = entry.Open();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream1.CopyTo(ms);
        return  ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```