# create ZIP file in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

We plan to use  React or Angular for the client frontend.

I need to zip files in the client machine and send it to the backend via REST API.

Do let me know if this is possible. Any pointers to get this done would be helpful.

Comment: There were redundant statements in the original question. Also there was unnecessary information provided.

For e.g. The backend stack is not important in this question. 

The information about the extensions is also unnecessary. If you are able to zip up one type, you should be able to zip any.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099549/is-it-possible-to-generate-zip-file-and-download-in-angular-4) question which is very similar.

Comment: @Mathyn Is this possible send ZIP file to the backend via REST API. On the fly using JSZIP npm module

Comment: Yes you can, just grab the output of JSZip and send it to your back-end in whatever format you need.

Comment: @Mathyn thanks for your quick response, will check and get back to you soon

Comment: If you want to zip the files purely to avoid multiple requests to the API, there are simpler ways to do it than zipping. Assuming you can change the API, you could send the files as a "multipart" form body, which would be the most standard way. If not but you don't care about compression, [client-zip](https://github.com/Touffy/client-zip) (yes, shameless self-promotion here ;)) is a lot faster and smaller than JSZip.