# Angular: How to download a file from HttpClient?

Tags: angular, typescript, file, blob, angular-httpclient

I need download an excel from my backend, its returned a file.

When I do the request I get the error:

> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You
>   can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

My code is:

```
this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/...`)
      .subscribe(response => this.downloadFile(response, "application/ms-excel"));
```

I tried get and map(...) but didn't work.

Details: **angular 5.2**

references:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Content-Type of response:

```
Content-Type: application/ms-excel
```

What's wrong?

Comment: what line and column is the error at ?

Comment: Post `downloadFile(....)` function as well???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download excel/Zip files in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46153118/9775003).

Comment: I tried the responses from that link, but not work well. Here I got the solution!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try something like this:

> type: application/ms-excel

```
/**
 *  used to get file from server
 */

this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}`,{
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers} 
         ).subscribe(response => this.downLoadFile(response, "application/ms-excel"));


    /**
     * Method is use to download file.
     * @param data - Array Buffer data
     * @param type - type of the document.
     */
    downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
        let blob = new Blob([data], { type: type});
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let pwa = window.open(url);
        if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {
            alert( 'Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got an error using Angular 9:

Type '"arraybuffer"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.ts(2322)
http.d.ts(1097, 9): The expected type comes from property 'responseType'.

Comment: @programmer-man You now need to do something like: resposeType:  'arrayheaders' as 'json' , see Hasan's answer.

Comment: I modify the download file and I can set the filename and works perfect me:
`
  downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    const fileName = 'file1.xlsx';
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = 'display: none';
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
`

Answer (score 138):

Blobs are returned with file type from backend. The following function will accept any file type and popup download window:

```
downloadFile(route: string, filename: string = null): void{

    const baseUrl = 'http://myserver/index.php/api';
    const token = 'my JWT';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('authorization','Bearer '+token);
    this.http.get(baseUrl + route,{headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}).subscribe(
        (response: any) =>{
            let dataType = response.type;
            let binaryData = [];
            binaryData.push(response);
            let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: dataType}));
            if (filename)
                downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Great answer!. I would also add "downloadLink.parentNode.removeChild(downloadLink);"
after "downloadLink.click();". Just to keep it clear.

Comment: after trying several suggestion from this page, a variation of this answer solved my issue

Comment: This seems to be the better answer for todays needs and capabilities. It sets the file name using the newer HTML standards. I didn't need the JWT part because we use an intercepter service to add authorization.

Comment: why `'blob' as 'json'`? I think you can only say `responseType: 'blob'`.

Comment: @Mojtaba cuz typing.

Comment: Is this working in Android and Iphone both?

Comment: One question:- Why we are not using a tag directly here?

Comment: sorry but it won't work for file type .msg & .eml on edge..... what to do then ?

Comment: Does the `a` need to actually be added to the body?  I didn't `appendChild` the `a` and it worked fine.

Comment: Man you are a saviour , you saved a lot of my effort

Comment: `a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))`
instead of
`document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();`

Answer (score 27):

It took me a while to implement the other responses, as **I'm using Angular 8 (tested up to 13)**.  I ended up with the following code (heavily inspired by Hasan).

Note that for the name to be set, the header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` MUST include `Content-Disposition`.  To set this in django RF:

```
http_response = HttpResponse(package, content_type='application/javascript')
http_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
http_response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = "Content-Disposition"
```

In angular:

```
  // component.ts
  // getFileName not necessary, you can just set this as a string if you wish
  getFileName(response: HttpResponse<Blob>) {
    let filename: string;
    try {
      const contentDisposition: string = response.headers.get('content-disposition');
      const r = /(?:filename=")(.+)(?:;")/
      filename = r.exec(contentDisposition)[1];
    }
    catch (e) {
      filename = 'myfile.txt'
    }
    return filename
  }

  
  downloadFile() {
    this._fileService.downloadFile(this.file.uuid)
      .subscribe(
        (response: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
          let filename: string = this.getFileName(response)
          let binaryData = [];
          binaryData.push(response.body);
          let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
          downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: 'blob' }));
          downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          downloadLink.click();
        }
      )
  }

  // service.ts
  downloadFile(uuid: string) {
    return this._http.get<Blob>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/v1/file/${uuid}/package/`, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it works and I've been using it for a few weeks now, but I came across the fact, that it only works up to a certain filesize. If the returned data is too large (like 1 - 2 MB), the download window doesn't show up. Plus: Even if it worked, on real big files, you wouldn't see the save dialog until all the data has been received. Not a real download...

Comment: thanks, it worked except for the regex, I'm using asp.net and so the content disposition was a bit different, mine looks like this: '/(?:filename=)(.+)(?:;)/'

Comment: Thanks! Can confirm this also works with Angular 13

Comment: Like this answer as it uses a file name sent from the server, however, the regex fails when the file name has space(s) so I tried fixing the regex to `(?:filename="?)([^"]+)(?:("?;))`. Have a quick test at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/as9EAF/1)

Answer (score 9):

Using Blob out put from API (Excel FIle)

and tweaked @gabrielrincon answer

```
downloadExcel(): void {
const payload = {
  order: 'test',
  };

this.service.downloadExcel(payload)
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.blobToFile(res, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Export.xlsx");
  });}
```

blob to file common function

```
blobToFile(data: any, type: string, fileName: string) {
 const a = document.createElement('a');
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.style.display = 'none';
 const blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
 const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 a.href = url; a.download = fileName; a.click();
 window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);}
```

in the blob to file function we are expecting first parameter as our blob data, type of file and pass file name including extention 1. we are creating an html a tag element 2. then we append the element in html 3. then hide the a tag element 4. then create new blob object with file and type 5. we will convert the blob object to URL 6. then appened that URL to href property of our a tag 7. we are opening our URL in window so it will download

Comment: Can you please explain the blobToFile function?

Comment: in the blob to file function we are expecting first parameter as our blob data, type of file and pass file name including extention

1. we are creating an html a tag element
2. then we append the element in html
3. then hide the a tag element
4. then create new blob object with file and type
5. we will convert the blob object to URL
6. then  appened that URL to href property of our a tag
7. we are opening our URL in window so it will download

Comment: Thanks. Btw how can I display a message on any error?

Comment: Say for example if the file is not found I wanted to display a message in my UI

Answer (score 5):

I ended up here when searching for ”rxjs download file using post”.

This was my final product. It uses the file name and type given in the server response.

```
import { ajax, AjaxResponse } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

downloadPost(url: string, data: any) {
    return ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'blob',
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'text/plain, */*',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        }
    }).pipe(
        map(handleDownloadSuccess),
    );
}


handleDownloadSuccess(response: AjaxResponse) {
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.response);

    const disposition = response.xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
    if (disposition) {
        const filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
        const matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
        if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
            const filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After spending much time searching for a response to this answer: how to download a simple image from my API restful server written in Node.js into an Angular component app, I finally found a beautiful answer in this web [Angular HttpClient Blob](https://brianflove.com/2017/11/02/angular-http-client-blob/). Essentially it consist on:

**API Node.js restful:**

```
   /* After routing the path you want ..*/
  public getImage( req: Request, res: Response) {

    // Check if file exist...
    if (!req.params.file) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.badRequest).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: 'File param not found.'
      })
    }
    const absfile = path.join(STORE_ROOT_DIR,IMAGES_DIR, req.params.file);

    if (!fs.existsSync(absfile)) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.badRequest).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: 'File name not found on server.'
      })
    }
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(absfile));
  }
```

**Angular 6 tested component service (EmployeeService on my case):**

```
  downloadPhoto( name: string) : Observable<Blob> {
    const url = environment.api_url + '/storer/employee/image/' + name;

    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .pipe(
        takeWhile( () => this.alive),
        filter ( image => !!image));
  }
```

**Template**

```
 <img [src]="" class="custom-photo" #photo>
```

**Component subscriber and use:**

```
@ViewChild('photo') image: ElementRef;

public LoadPhoto( name: string) {
    this._employeeService.downloadPhoto(name)
          .subscribe( image => {
            const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
            this.image.nativeElement.src= url;
          }, error => {
            console.log('error downloading: ', error);
          })    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

May be I am late. But last answer by @Hasan was superb.

I just make little changes(this was not accepting headers so removed) in this and got success.

> ```
> downloadFile(route: string, filename: string = null): void {
>     // const baseUrl = 'http://myserver/index.php/api';   
>     this.http.get(route, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(
>       (response: any) => {
>         let dataType = response.type;
>         let binaryData = [];
>         binaryData.push(response);
>         let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
>         downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));
>         if (filename) {
>           downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
>         }
>         document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
>         downloadLink.click();
>       }
>     )
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Blob` as a source for an `img`:

**template:**

```html
<img [src]="url">
```

**component:**

```js
 public url : SafeResourceUrl;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this.getImage('/api/image.jpg').subscribe(x => this.url = x)
 }

 public getImage(url: string): Observable<SafeResourceUrl> {
   return this.http
     .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
     .pipe(
       map(x => {
         const urlToBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(x) // get a URL for the blob
         return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(urlToBlob); // tell Anuglar to trust this value
       }),
     );
 }
```

Further reference about [trusting save values](https://angular.io/guide/security)

Comment: I needed those bits about `SafeResourceUrl` and `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` to resolve problems I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, i am stunned by all the complicated proposed solutions.

If your backend returns the `attachment` flag and the `filename` property in its `Content-Disposition`, you can simply make this javascript call.

```
window.location = `${environment.apiUrl}/...`;
```

The browser will download the file without changing the current page.

Comment: Does this work with API authorization?