# How to code for downloading a file in angular 6

Tags: angular

I wanted to download file, I am new in angular, so I can't understand what do I do

```html
<img src="assets/images/download.png" alt="IMG-LOGO" height="20" width="20" (click)="getfile(product.product_id)">
```

and in ts file I wrote function for api call

```js
getfile(id){

        this.filter.productid = id;
        this.apiService.getfile(this.filter).subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
            this.fileUrl = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How download a file from HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682514/how-download-a-file-from-httpclient)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to leverage angular to trigger the file download?  HTML can do this without any help...  Just change your code to something like this:

```html
<a href="/path/to/file/{{ product.product_id }} ">
    <img src="assets/images/download.png" alt="IMG-LOGO" height="20" width="20">
</a>
```

Comment: Yes, although, you may have to alter the headers from the server-side code to force the download, but from the front end, this is how to do it.

Comment: Also, if you reference @zmag post above, he mentions using 'target="_blank"'...  That can't hurt, either.

Comment: And to add extra clarity...  You CAN initiate a download with JavaScript, but since you have to implement this using extra code for something HTML does out of the box, don't do it...

Comment: I have no idea what language/framework your server side is written with...

Comment: In that case, I don't know how you're managing files within Codeigniter, which web server you're running, whether your web server is set up correctly, whether your file permissions are set correctly, etc.  This is a completely different problem than getting files to download using AngularJS.  My suggestion would be to mark this question as solved, and post a different problem in the CodeIgniter channel.

Answer (score -1):

Your goal is just to download a file, you don't have to struggle with Angular. simply link it with `a` tag.

```html
<a href="/download/id" target="_blank">
  <img src="assets/images/download.png" alt="IMG-LOGO" height="20" width="20">
</a>
```

Comment: it's not working i am getting blank output, i can not download it

Comment: just using an href also won't work if you have a protected api. And this href is pointing to a root relative path, but the example above is using an api service...